# In an opamp differentiator, how does high gain produce oscillations?

Tags: operational-amplifier

The gain of an ideal differentiator increases 20dB/dec - this means the gain increases as frequency increases. I'm wondering **how high gain produces oscillations.**

I've read so many times that negative feedback stabilizes the op amp but never quite get why the opamp needs stabilizing. I understand high gain is useless because a small input signal can saturate the output of opamp. Also I understand how the negative feedback reduces offset voltage, but that's it.

I don't get how high gain produces oscillations.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109176/discussion-on-question-by-beccaboo-in-an-opamp-differentiator-how-does-high-gai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I made a simple simulation in LTspice assuming Vin = 0V:

[image]

And the output voltage looks like this:

[image]

And the frequency of this oscillation is equal to:

$$F = \sqrt{F_T \times F_{RC}} = \sqrt{1MHz \times \frac{0.16}{10\textrm{nF} \times 10\textrm{k}\Omega}} \approx 40\textrm{kHz}$$

Adding a resistor in series with the capacitor may fix the circuit because now at high frequency the feedback network phase shift is 0 degrees.

Comment: Nice result, (+1) and, did you try putting 1 ohm (or more) in series with C1 to see if it stops oscillating? That would be a nice touch.

Comment: @Andyaka 5 ohm kills oscillations.

Comment: that's quite high for a differentiator. Never thought it would be that high.